# How to properly apply margins in Firefox on a Google Apps Script UI

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using margins to position elements (and add space between elements) in my Web App that I created with Google Apps Script UiInstance.

The margins are not being applied properly in Firefox or Opera. They are being applied in Chrome and Internet Explorer, so I feel that the code is correct.

Here is an example which I have [published here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbypbMK6plywsHKaDZYq2WtQ8uzEqoNcEfTN1HacJu-atILgXQjq/exec).

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.createLabel("Some Text").setStyleAttribute("margin-left","500px").setStyleAttribute("margin-top","25px"));
  return app;
}
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Is this a bug, or is this bad practice and I should do something else?

Note: Using the Firefox inspector, I found nothing that would indicate a margin was attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax issue, try it like this

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setStandardsMode(false);
  app.add(app.createLabel("Some Text").setStyleAttribute("marginLeft","500px").setStyleAttribute("marginTop","25px"));
  return app;
}
```

or like this

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setStandardsMode(false);
  app.add(app.createLabel("Some Text").setStyleAttributes({marginLeft :"500px",marginTop :"25px"}));
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This fixed it. CamelCase margins seemed to work whereas the dashed ones did not. Odd, but I guess that's the way it is.

Comment: I've read that somewhere in the doc but right now I just can't find where it was...(if I find it I'll post it as reference)

Comment: just found it [the CSS attribute, in camelCase. ("fontSize", not "font-size")](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_textbox?hl=en).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for remembering.